# Há como abrir uma tabela SQL direto num data.table, sem fazer o caminho SQL > data.frame > data.table?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, big-data, data.rable-r

Desejo abrir uma tabela SQL direto num data.table. Quando faço uma query com `dbGetQuery`, o que obtenho é um data.frame. Eu sei que depois posso transformar esse data.frame num data.table facilmente. Mas eu gostaria de pular essa etapa -- que em determinadas ocasiões pode não ser computacionalmente eficiente.

Abaixo um código mínimo reprodutível:

```
    library(sqldf)
    library(data.table)

    A <- data.frame(var1 = 1:10, var2=55:64)
    drv <- dbDriver("SQLite") 
    con <- dbConnect(drv, "basequalquer.db") 
    dbWriteTable(con, "TabelaA", A)
```

Na linha de comando abaixo, estou aplicando o comando `data.table` sobre o resultado do `dbGetQuery` (que vem como data.frame). É exatamente isso que eu NÃO gostaria de fazer...

```
    data.table(dbGetQuery(con, "Select * from TabelaA"))
        row_names var1 var2
     1:         1    1   55
     2:         2    2   56
     3:         3    3   57
     4:         4    4   58
     5:         5    5   59
     6:         6    6   60
     7:         7    7   61
     8:         8    8   62
     9:         9    9   63
    10:        10   10   64
```

Sugestões?

Comment: essa resposta do Stack Overflow em Inglês pode ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20346697/3297472
Acho que usando a função `setDT` a conversão do data.frame para data.table fica eficiente, mas não testei.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dando uma fuçada no código descrobri que o segredo está na função `fetch`, que é uma implementação feita no pacote `RSQLite`, para objetos do tipo `SQLiteResult` (classe S4), que implementa o método genérico de mesmo nome definido no pacote `DBI`. No seu código, a função `dbGetQuery` usa `fetch`. Assim, primeiro vou reproduzir seu código isolando a função `fetch`:

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

A <- data.frame(var1 = 1:10, var2=55:64)
drv <- dbDriver("SQLite") 
con <- dbConnect(drv, "basequalquer.db") 
dbWriteTable(con, "TabelaA", A) 
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "Select * from TabelaA")
fetch(res)
```

Olhando no [código fonte](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/blob/f431ce83cd1e57372edf4c1c4ce970cc88471eb5/R/Result.R) do pacote `RSQLite`, podemos ver que `fetch` chama a função `sqliteFetch`, copiada abaixo, que por sua vez chama um algoritmo em C, que faz todo o trabalho sujo e retorna `NULL` ou uma `list`.

```
sqliteFetch <- function(res, n = 0) {  
  check_valid(res)

  # Returns NULL, or a list
  rel <- .Call(rsqlite_query_fetch, res@Id, nrec = as.integer(n))
  if (is.null(rel)) return(data.frame())

  attr(rel, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(length(rel[[1]]))
  attr(rel, "class") <- "data.frame"
  rel
}
```

Note que o resultado `rel` torna-se um `data.frame` depois disso. Você poderia até  tentar transformar essa lista em `data.table`, mas isso não seria muito diferente de transformar um `data.frame` em um `data.table`.

Assim, a menos que alguém já tenha implementado uma solução alternativa, para resolver seu problema você teria de reimplementar a função em C para que retorne um objeto do tipo `data.table` (que basicamente é um `data.frame` com um ponteiro como atributo). Além disso, você precisaria mudar a definição genérica de `fetch`, que espera como resultado um `data.frame` ([veja aqui](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI/blob/master/R/DBResult.R)).

Eu particularmente não acho que valeria à pena, pois o ganho em eficiência não seria tão significativo, mas o esforço seria.

A propósito, sugiro que considere a utilização do fantástico pacote `dplyr`, que possui funções para extração eficiente de bases de dados, usando "avaliação preguiçosa" (basicamente, você pode usar as funções `mutate`, `filter`, `select`, etc. do vocabulário do `dplyr` e o pacote magicamente transforma essas operações em SQL **antes** de baixar os dados, o que pode resultar em um enorme ganho em transferência de dados). Além disso, o pacote foi feito para ser intuitivo e fácil de usar. Veja [aqui](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html).

Comment: + 1 bons comentários